# Could I write foreign wrapper in postgresql to enable it use third party index?

Tags: postgresql

I have created a foreign data wrapper to extend datatype of PostgreSQL, the data are retrieved from third party sdk and there exists index for the data, could I use the index directly ? thanks.

Comment: Closevoted "unclear what you're asking". This is too vague and general to be possible to answer usefully. Please describe *in detail* what the "third party sdk", the "index" that exists there, etc are, what the data is, what form you want to retrieve it in, etc. I *think* what you might be asking is *When a user queries a foreign table with my FDW and supplies a WHERE clause that matches an index on the remote end, can my foreign data wrapper find out what the WHERE predicate is and execute it on the remote end?*. That's a WAG though.

Comment: @Craig Ringer, this is exactly what I mean, I have such idea but do not know how to realize it, could you please provide some steps or documents about this? thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index is no value in itself, it points to the data. So I would say: wrong idea.

Unless there is something very special in *third party sdk* (?).